# Error while running a thread that listens for a tcp connection alongside the main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have a program that makes calculations based on incoming data from a sensor. The program also looks for an incoming request for a TCP connection. I placed the code to look for a connection in a function called: void LookForConnection(). And this function is part of the class: communicate. I would like to run this function simultaneously as a thread alongside the main thread, that is found in main.cpp. But when I try to implement this and call the LookForConnection() function I get the **error: invalid use of void expression.**

I tried to replace void with int and let it return something and also giving the function a value along but I end up getting errors. What is the correct way to call this function?

Declaration of the function in communicate.h
`void LookForConnection();`

Funtion Implementation in communicate.cpp and class communicate

```
void communicate::LookForConnection()
    {
        close(socket_desc);
        close(new_socket);
        shutdown(socket_desc,SHUT_RDWR);
        shutdown(new_socket,SHUT_RDWR);
        server.sin_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        this_thread::sleep_for(65s); // Waits for the port to be free

        //Create socket
        socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

        if (socket_desc == -1)
            {
            cout << "Error: Could not create socket" << endl;
            }
        //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server.sin_port = htons( PORT );

        //Bind
        if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == -1 )
            {
            cout << "Error: Bind failed" << endl;
            }

        //Listen
        listen(socket_desc , 3);

        //Accept and incoming connection
        cout << "Waiting for incoming connections..." << endl;
        c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
        if (new_socket<0)
        {
        cout << "Error: Accept failed" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
        cout << "Connection accepted" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Function call in main.cpp

```
if(rec == "1043")
            {
            std::thread t1; // Make thread t1
            do  {
                // co is a object of the communicate class
                t1(co.LookForConnection()); // Connects function to thread which closes the socket and after 65 sec looks for a connection
                }
            while(true);
                {
                cout << "Program is running" << endl;
                if(co.Run() == "1052") // Value that stops the while loop from running
                    {
                    t1.join(); // Waits till thread t1 is done
                    break;  // Out of the while loop
                    }
                }
            break; //Out bigger while loop
            }
```

Comment: You are *calling* the function and passing its return value to the `std::thread` constructor. You are supposed to pass the function *itself* to the constructor. The linked duplicate explains how to do that for non-static member functions.

Comment: Sorry, you are not passing it to the constructor. You are trying to call the `std::thread` object itself. That is not possible, `std::thread` has no `operator()`.